# Set time duration for a quiz in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello im trying to make a quiz app where users can take a quiz but have to finish it within a time frame. I have done the quiz creation part and user can join to complete the quiz but now im stuck on how to add time functionality. Can someone help me in this part?

So from your guys answers i did this
Added a js countdown timer in frontend like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeoutHandle;
    function countdown(minutes) {
        var seconds = 60;
        var mins = minutes
        function tick() {
            var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
            var current_minutes = mins-1
            seconds--;
            counter.innerHTML =
            current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
            if( seconds > 0 ) {
                timeoutHandle=setTimeout(tick, 1000);
            } else {
                if(mins > 1){
                   // countdown(mins-1);   never reach “00″ issue solved:Contributed by Victor Streithorst
                   setTimeout(function () { countdown(mins - 1); }, 1000);
                }
            }
        }
        tick();
    }
    countdown('<?php echo $time; ?>');
    </script>
    
    <!-- script for disable url -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var time= '<?php echo $time; ?>';
        var realtime = time*60000;
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert('Time Out');
            window.location.href= '/';},
       realtime);
        
    </script>
```

In my backend i have the quiz table with a cloumn integer called duration, now should i add another column as a time stamp?

Comment: If you share the code you are stuck with, maybe someone can help. We are not gonna write the code for you.

Comment: @GertB.I will edit to show the code

Answer (score 3):

You can create a timestamp when you return the question view. Then you start a timer in javascript in the fronted, so the user how much time is left. But because you can't trust the frontend, you check if the timestamp that is within X seconds (a threshold) of what the server thinks the time is. This way you validate the answer was given in a certain time, without blocking out legit requests that were just a little slow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What type of quiz you want ? Full questions to send at once, one question to validate and go to the next ? But mainly you do :

- Create timestamp server side (depends on your quiz timer you want)
- Create a timer client side for the view with timestamp sent from server
- Never trust client side so check server side the timer
- When user validate quiz check is timer is still running (if not you could just redirect to page with "quiz done")
- Client side you can send the to server a value when timer is zero (but refer to "never trust client side") to stop the quiz

You can do "non blocking" requests to the server with ajax requests for the timer.

Comment: So i added a js function in the front, now the backend part how to check the time can u se the updated answer. Sorry for any hard time

Comment: with timestamps (which are integers) you can do a '-' operation

Comment: Added the script above, please look at the updated answer but shows an error: Undefined variable: time

Comment: countdown('<?php echo $time; ?>'); -> you never used a variable called "time"

Comment: How can i fix that, cuz in another project it works like a charm